# Suppress unsaved changes message in Cuba Platform

Tags: cuba-platform

I have a lookup screen with authors and I load the data by using a custom query in init from AuthorsBrowse::AbstractLookup. I manipulate the data I want to display, but the changes should not be saved.

If I close the tab i get this message dialog:

You have unsaved changes
Do you want to discard unsaved changes?

How can I suppress this message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This message appears if anything datasource was changed.

If you want suppress message, you need to add to datasource (that was changed) attribute `allowCommit="false"`, like that:

```xml
<collectionDatasource id="authorsDs"
                      class="com.haulmont.workshop.core.entity.Author"
                      view="_local"  allowCommit="false">
    <query>
        <![CDATA[
        select e from ws$Author e where e.status = 10
        ]]>
    </query>
</collectionDatasource>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also implement a more fine-grained control over the unsaved changes behavior of your screen if the screen implements `Window.Committable` interface. The interface contains `isModified()` method which returns a boolean value.

`AbstractEditor` already implements this interface and its `isModified()` looks as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean isModified() {
    return getDsContext() != null && getDsContext().isModified();
}
```

You can implement `Window.Committable` in your browser screen and just return false or write some logic in `isModified()`.